# Temporarily Save data in datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows

Is it possible to save data in datagridview temporarily, by c# & windows form?

To clarify:
After add data in datagridview and close form and after that open form again this data not clear!

Note: i don't want get all data from database in the datagridview, I mean just added data before close form

Comment: Since you are using a Windows Application, it is easy, you can use a Global `DataTable` to hold the Data which you want to display. Once your form is reloaded, bind the DataTable to DataGridView

Comment: thats not possible because when you close the form it gets destroyed so does its all controls(Grid) along with your data...when you open form again all elements recreated...so one way could be store data in local datatable object and use it to bind to grid (the same data every time form opens)...do go through windows form page lifecycle here is the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Let's clarify: You want to persist the data a user enteres between programm runs? And you don't have a DataSource? - I would serialize the data into an xml file. you may use all text fields or types that fit your data..